# Get nested UserRoles from User table

Tags: c#, linq

I am querying from Database and there are nested tables. My query looks like this:

```
  System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> applicationUsers = await _userManager.Users
        .Include(u => u.UserRoles).ToListAsync();
```

I would like to get all UserRole ID's and role names, so I have done this:

```
  IEnumerable<List<UserRole>> userRoles = applicationUsers.Select(person => person.UserRoles.Select(u => new UserRole
        {
          Id = u.RoleId,
          RoleName = u.Role.ToString(),
        }).ToList());
```

However as an output I am getting `IEnumerable<List<UserRole>>` when I need `List<UserRole>`. What I am doing wrong?

**UserRole.cs:**

```
  public class UserRole
  {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public bool Successful { get; set; }

  }
```

Comment: Try replacing first select with SelectMany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
List<UserRole> userRoles = applicationUsers.SelectMany(person => person.UserRoles).ToList();
```